# Error in cross compiling of linux kernel

Tags: assembly, linux-kernel

I build gcc7.3 as a cross compiler for arm926ej-s processor.
After that i try to build linux kernel 2.6.32.17 for my arm processor.
But i get this error in building the kernel:

.../arch/arm/include/asm/irqflags.h:35:2: error: invalid lvalue in asm output 0

irqflags.h is a header file in the source of linux kernel.
Can any body help me to fix this error?
Thank you.

Comment: It's an error in something that uses the `raw_local_irq_save` macro. There's probably more error messages that give an indication of what that something is.

Comment: Your kernel is 8 years old; possibly it does something that used to work but is incompatible with modern gcc.  (Also FYI, the 2.6.32 stable series hasn't been supported since 2016-Feb.  https://news.softpedia.com/news/linux-kernel-2-6-32-lts-reaches-end-of-life-on-february-2016-499661.shtml.)  Linux 4.14 might be a good choice if you want to try a kernel that isn't obsolete.   (https://news.softpedia.com/news/linux-4-14-to-be-the-next-lts-kernel-series-supported-for-at-least-2-years-516520.shtml).  The oldest LTS kernel series is currently 3.16 (https://www.kernel.org/).

Comment: what have you tried thus far?  what does that line of code look like, post the code and your attempts and results.

Comment: Thank you for replays.  Ross Ridge you are right. There is an error in some lines above this error message. That error is:
mm/swap.c:340:45: error: ‘flags’ undeclared (first use in this function); did you mean ‘fls’?
     spin_unlock_irqrestore(&zone->lru_lock, flags);
In mentioned file, line 332 there is a declaration for flags as fallow:
unsigned long uninitialized_var(flags);

Comment: Did you patch your kernel with a driver or something?  That kind of compile error sounds like a patch that didn't apply cleanly.

Comment: @ebi: Instead of putting error message into comments, [edit] your question post and add this message into it. Such a way your problem can be understanded without viewing bunch of comments.

Comment: I am working with a board that it's processor is  arm926ej-s. Creator company of this board, prepare the linux kernel 2.6.32.17 along with proper drivers for different peripherals of it.I am trying to compile this kernel.I don't path this kernel but perhaps the creator company did.

Answer (score 0):

To solve this error I add

## uninitialized_var(x) x = x macro

to compiler-gcc7.h file in .../include/linux/ directory.